# Resizing QGraphicsScene when layout changes

Tags: python, layout, pyside2

I'm using a QGraphicsScene in PySide2, and I want to resize its contents when the scene resizes. I'm able to trigger the resize when the main window resizes, but I can't figure out how to trigger it when the contents of the window change.

Here's a small example where I have a graphics scene and two push buttons. In the scene is a circle that should just touch the edges. When I click one of the buttons, it shows or hides the other button.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import QResizeEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QDialog,
                               QSizePolicy, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView)


class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        # Create widgets
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.circle = self.scene.addEllipse(0, 0, 10, 10)
        self.extra = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.extra.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Button 2")
        # Create layout and add widgets
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.extra)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        # Set dialog layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # Add button signal to greetings slot
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)

    def on_click1(self):
        self.button2.setVisible(not self.button2.isVisible())
        self.resizeEvent()

    def on_click2(self):
        self.button1.setVisible(not self.button1.isVisible())
        self.resizeEvent()

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent = None):
        size = self.extra.maximumViewportSize()
        target_size = min(size.width(), size.height()) - 1
        self.circle.setRect((size.width() - target_size) // 2,
                            (size.height() - target_size) // 2,
                            target_size,
                            target_size)
        self.extra.scene().setSceneRect(0, 0, size.width(), size.height())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    # Run the main Qt loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The scene is resized when the main window resizes and when one of the buttons disappears or reappears. The circle adjusts its size when the main window resizes, but not when the buttons change.

How can I handle the resizing when the buttons change? I'd like to keep the circle just touching the edge of the display as it resizes.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the possible duplicate, but I found `fitInView()` didn't give me the fine control I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was handling the resize of the main window, and not the graphics view. Create a new subclass of `QGraphicsView`, and handle the resize event there. It will catch both kinds of resize event.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import QResizeEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QDialog,
                               QSizePolicy, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QWidget)


class ResizingView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.circle = self.scene().addEllipse(0, 0, 1, 1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        size = event.size()
        target_size = min(size.width(), size.height()) - 1
        x = (size.width() - target_size) // 2
        y = (size.height() - target_size) // 2
        self.circle.setRect(x, y, target_size, target_size)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, size.width(), size.height())


class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        # Create widgets
        self.extra = ResizingView()
        self.extra.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Button 2")
        # Create layout and add widgets
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.extra)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        # Set dialog layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # Add button signal to greetings slot
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)

    def on_click1(self):
        self.button2.setVisible(not self.button2.isVisible())

    def on_click2(self):
        self.button1.setVisible(not self.button1.isVisible())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    # Run the main Qt loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you don't want to move all the resize logic into the graphics view, create a new signal on your subclass, and connect it to a slot on whatever class should handle the resize event. If this still isn't working for you, check that you're calling `setSceneRect()` on the graphics view.

If you don't like recalculating the sizes of everything, you may prefer the simpler approach of just scaling everything with the [`fitInView()` method](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QGraphicsView.html#id4). It's certainly easier, but I prefer the finer control you can have with a full set of size calculations. Here's an example of using `fitInView()`.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QResizeEvent, QColor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QDialog,
                               QSizePolicy, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QWidget)


class ResizingView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(scene=QGraphicsScene(), parent=parent)
        self.circle = self.scene().addEllipse(1, 1, 98, 98)
        self.scene().addSimpleText('Centre').setPos(50, 50)
        self.scene().setBackgroundBrush(QColor('green'))
        self.scene().setSceneRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):
        self.fitInView(0, 0, 100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        super().resizeEvent(event)


class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        # Create widgets
        self.extra = ResizingView()
        self.extra.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Button 2")
        # Create layout and add widgets
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.extra)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        # Set dialog layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # Add button signal to greetings slot
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)

    def on_click1(self):
        self.button2.setVisible(not self.button2.isVisible())

    def on_click2(self):
        self.button1.setVisible(not self.button1.isVisible())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    # Run the main Qt loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Either way, the key thing is to subclass `QGraphicsView` and handle its `resizeEvent()` instead of the one on the main form.